# Was bedeutet »steht« hier?

Tags: meaning

> Der Wald steht schwarz und schweiget.

Das Verb **»stehen«** bedeutet *stand*, *suit* auf Englisch.

Aber hier weiß ich nicht, was es bedeutet.

Comment: »The forest **stands** black and is silent.« - It's a poetic speech.

Comment: (+1) But, technically, `the forest stands black and *is* silent`, since schweigt is a verb, nort an adjective.  Personally, I think "***dark*** and silent" sounds better - more ... threatening ... ominous. So rather than word word translation, `the forst stands dark and silent`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is from a poem/song (Abendlied „Der Mond ist aufgegangen“ by Matthias Claudius), so language use differs from common German use and is open to interpretation.

I'd consider this line as a case of personification (*Personifizierung*), where the *Wald* gets human qualities.

**steht**: The *Wald* is standing around; basically meaning "there is" a Wald and it is not doing much (no activity, it is just there).

**schweiget** (normally it would be *schweigt*, from *schweigen*/to keep silent): Another personification meaning the *Wald* is not saying anything, is quiet (no birds singing, no rustling leaves...). This kind of goes together with *Der Wald steht* (no activity).

**schwarz** (black): I'd associate with darkness (evening/night) or perhaps a very dense forest.

Comment: Apparently, "*Der Wald steht schwarz und schweiget*" is also the title (based on the song/poem) of a Tatort.

Comment: `schwarz` makes perfect sense in terms of darkness. If the moon has just risen, then it is more often than not during the night.

Answer (score 6):

### [stehen](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=stehen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0) (Bavarian Forest)

[image]
<sup>[Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Bayerischer_Wald_-_Aufichtenwald_001.jpg)</sup>

### [liegen](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=liegen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0) (Black Forest after a storm)

[image]
<sup>[Vitold Muratov: Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Vitold_Muratov)</sup>

<sub>**Note for learners:** The pictures illustrate that *stehen* can well be used in the context of trees and a forest but other than with trees we do not use *liegen* for a forest not even after a storm damage. Then, *liegen* has the meaning of *to be located in*.</sub>

Comment: =D Selten bei einer Antwort so gelacht (+1)

Comment: Don't want to spoil the fun, but would you really refer to these situations saying: *der Wald steht/liegt*?

Comment: @user1583209 - no of course not. With a forest we mostly use *"liegen"* as *to be located in* but the pictures do illustrate why *stehen* may have been used in the poem.

Comment: Could have been worth to make that clear with a few words. Personally I don't see this as the contrast you show in the pictures, but could imagine the following interpretation of "...steht schwarz..." as tall trees towering menacingly over the observer. This in contrast to "...liegen..." which I'd associate with sleep, lying down (therefore low height), calm....

Answer (score 1):

Zwei Eigenschaften kommen hier in Betracht:

1) stehen kommt vom Lateinische *stare*, ebenso wie *statisch*, keine Bewegung. Andere Beispiele:

- In München steht ein Hofbräuhaus
- An der Kreuzung steht ein Stoppschild

2) Eine nennenswerte Höhe des Gegenstandes. Bei einem See oder einem Zebrastreifen würde man eher *liegen* oder *sich befinden* verwenden (die allerdings auch beide auf einen Wald anwendbar wären).

Comment: "Oans, zwoa, gsuffa" führt zu mehr Verwirrung bei den Lesern, oder?

Answer (score 1):

Tatsächlich gibt es **Bäume** die "stehen und schweigen."

Aber ein Wald ist eine Sammlung von Bäumen.

Es is viel imponierender "Der Wald steht und schweigt," zu sagen, als "Die Bäume stehen und schweigen," zu sagen.

Das ist poetisch.

Comment: @user1583209: Thanks for your help.